# Use RegEx to find dates and increment year by a value

Tags: regex

I have a large number of files that contain dates. I would like to use a Regular Expression to find the dates and if possible increment the year of the date by 10.

The files can have multiple date formats ..

1. 04/22/78
2. 06-OCT-14

How would one write a regular expression that could find, increment, and replace the dates, or even just the year of the dates?

I plan to use a text editor like Text Pad, UltraEdit, or Notepad++ to search the files

Comment: do the date have same format, like DD[-/]MM[-/]YY? And what are the delimiters that are used?

Comment: Finding them all is probably doable, but incrementing would be a lot harder. You would be better off writing a small script in something more powerful than regex - say, a VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the pattern of date is `date.month.year`. `.` in date can be any field separator.

You can use simple `perl` program to do this:

```
perl -ne 's/(\d+)$/($1+10)/e && print' filename
```

This will add 10 to the year, and print the date.

Output for this is:

```
04/22/88
06-OCT-24
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I will have to look at how to read each line in a file from PERL and then spit it back out modified.

Comment: @webworm Just give the `filename` to the function, it will take each line from file and spit the output to `STDOUT`. You can redirect the output to another file.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrote this python snippet to get it done.

```
import re


def add_ten_years(date):
  reg = "((\d{2})(.)(\w{2,4})(.)(\d{2}))"
  mat = re.search(reg, date)
  if mat:
    mat = mat.groups()
    return ''.join(mat[1:5])+str(int(mat[5])+10)


print add_ten_years("04/22/78")
print add_ten_years("06-OCT-14")
```

You can configure the regex pattern to generalize it even more. Or can be easily translated to other languages. Hope it helped!

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been wanting to learn more about Python and maybe this is as good a chance as any other. Thanks for the snippet. It gives me a good place to start. Is Python a good language for text parsing? The files I have are sometimes many GB in size.

Comment: Python is a wonderful language for text parsing... I highly recommend. Well about size, you can either split or plan on moving to some parallel frameworks - I've worked on 2GB file on a 8GB machine. Otherwise you can just read line by line, process, and write.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to place this into a Python script that will accept a text file as input and then output an altered text file?